# How to open a trade requests to BingX API

Tags: python, exchange-server, signature

I'm working with Python to make some requests to the BingX API for Perpetual Swap Futures ([Documentation](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/#/swap)).
My problem is that when I try to open a position, I get an error. I know that my signature is correct since the other endpoints work correctly.

I've tried this with two requests:

```
r = requests.post(f'{api_url}{place_positions}?action=Open&apiKey={api_key_bing}&entrustPrice={buy}&entrustVolume={buy_volum}&side=Bid&stopLossPrice={sl_price}&symbol=BTC-USDT&takerProfitPrice={tp_price}&timestamp={timestamp}&tradeType=Market&sign={signature}')

r = requests.post(url=api_url + place_positions, data={'action': 'Open', 'apiKey': api_key_bing, 'entrustPrice': buy, 'entrustVolume': buy_volum, 'side': 'Bid','stopLossPrice': sl_price, 'symbol': 'BTC-USDT', 'takerProfitPrice': tp_price, 'timestamp': timestamp, 'tradeType': 'Market', 'sign': signature})
```

But this is the response I'm getting from the API:

> {'code': 80014, 'msg': 'Insufficient margin, please adjust and resubmit', 'data': {}}

And this has nothing to do with my account balance since I already added some founds and the request for getting my account info response shows it.

Also it isn't very clear to me what the parameters `entrustPrice` and `entrustVolume` mean.

Answer (score 1):

To open a trade using BingX API, you should use the following endpoint: [/openApi/swap/v2/trade/order](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/#/swapV2/trade-api.html#Trade%20order). If you have trouble implementing the API, feel free to take a look at my Python implementation of the API [py-bingx](https://github.com/amirinsight/py-bingx)

This endpoint can return the following response for multiple reasons:

```
{'code': 80014, 'msg': 'Insufficient margin, please adjust and resubmit', 'data': {}}
```

- You don't have enough funds in your account.
- Your funds are in the wrong trading account. You have multiple trading accounts in your main account for different trading purposes.
- Your leverage is too big and your funds can't cover the required margin.

Answer (score 0):

that's not a code issue. it seems like your fund is not in perpetual trading account. I assume either it's in standard future account or fund account.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).